# Multiple Connections through SSH

Tags: ssh, remote-access, remote

We have a server which we connect through and do remote tasks. However, around 4-5 people login with the same username and password. Can this situation cause anything weird?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Define weird ..

You will not be able to use history, or other last-used settings, in a meaningful manner as anyone could have used/set these last. You will also be unable to assign responsibility, if anything goes wrong.

*I don't recommend this practice, unless you don't care what happens to this server (and its content).*

---

*The SSH sessions themselves will be fine.*

I have maintained more than one session, when monitoring command-line transfers or configuration, with no issues.

Comment: Well thanks for the answer so the best option would be to create new users I presume. By the way how can I check which users (ips for example) are connected and how many ssh connections are present at a given time?

Comment: Yes, and you should use accounts with ***sudo*** rights. Then *sudo logs* will tell you what you need.

Comment: @vesnog `w` or `who`

Comment: @david6 Is sudo logs an additional command or you are talking about something else?

Comment: No, its log data that is collected in: **/var/log/auth.log**. Try this command: **`tail -f /var/log/auth.log`** OR **`cat /var/log/auth.log | grep sudo | tail -20`**